# Data Modelling question - Java/ Spring- Implementing Mutually exclusive association

Tags: java, sql, jpa, data-modeling

I am trying to build a Book app.
The entities are so-

The Entity `User` has a field called `Role` which specifies if this is an `Author` or `Reviewer`. Currently, I am using an Enum data member to differentiate if the User is an `Author` or `Reviewer.` One single instance of a User cannot be both.

A `Book` will have 1...* `Authors`- So a User entity which is an `Author` will have a many-to-many relation with entity Book

A `Book` will have 1...* `Reviewers`- So a User entity which is a `Reviewer` will have a many-to-many relation with entity `Book`

I was wondering how would I implement the User side - I preferably want one single collection of Books- If the User is an Author, this will contain a reference to the books he has authored. If it is a reviewer, it will contain references to the books on which he is a reviewer.

I am wondering if there is any construct in JPA/ Hibernate which can enable this.

I could always implement `Author` and `Reviewer` as different entities, but I still want to know the answer to such a situation which I presume must be quite commonly encountered.

Comment: I would say this is a scenario in which it makes sense for `Author` and `Reviewer` to be separate entities. Of course, you'll likely want for both of them to still inherit from a common base `User` entity. Having a single collection for authored and reviewed books is a code smell, because the meaning of that collection property becomes ambiguous

Comment: As a side note, if `User` represents an actual user profile in your app, then I'm not sure I'd want to directly mix this technical concept with business concepts like `Reviewer` or `Author`. Personally, I would design `Author`s and `Reviewer`s so that they merely *reference* a `User`, not *represent* it

Comment: @crizzis Thank you for the clarification. Indeed the collection would become ambiguous if I tried to mix both the types. As for the last part of your second comment, could you explain a bit briefly how you would go about doing that? Does it make sense to make User as the parent class and Author and Reviewer as child classes?